# how to join 5 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 5 tables in my db.movies. Like this:

**db.movies**

```
id | title   | plot
------------------
1  | matrix  | ddd
```

**db.aka**

```
id | movie_id | aka_title | aka_country
----------------------------------------
1  | 1        | neo       | usa
```

**db.genre**

```
id | genre_id | movie_id 
------------------------
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 2        | 1
```

**db.genre_name**

```
id | genre_name
---------------
1  | sci-fi
2  | action
```

**db.tags**

```
id | movie_id | keyword
-----------------------
1 | 1         | hacker
2 | 1         | computer
```

How do I create db.movies table like this:

**db.movies**

```
id | title   | plot | genre          | aka | aka_country | tags
1  | matrix  | ddd  | sci-fi, action | neo | usa         | hacker, computer
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: "how to join 5 tables" --- exactly the same like 2 tables, but several times.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for this:

```
select m.id,
    m.title,
    m.plot,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct g.genre_name)  as genre,
    a.aka_title,
    a.aka_country,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.keyword) keyword
from movies m
left join aka a
    on m.id = a.movie_id
left join genre g
    on m.id =g.movie_id
left join genre_name gn
    on g.genre_id = gn.id
left join tags t
    on m.id = t.movie_id
group by m.id
```

I do not know why you would want to then store this data in another table, I am guessing that you just mean results not table. The `LEFT JOIN` will allow records to be returned if any of the tables have no records present.

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0691/20)

Comment: Good point anbout the left join, if any of these tables might not have records fora particular movie, you need a left join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select
    mov.id,
    mov.title,
    mov.plot,
    group_concat(distinct genre_name) as genre,
    aka_title as aka,
    aka_country,
    group_concat(distinct keyword) as tags
from movies mov
join aka on mov.id = aka.movie_id
join genre gen on mov.id = gen.movie_id
join genre_name gna on gen.genre_id = gna.id
join tags tag on mov.id = tag.movie_id
group by mov.id;
```

## See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24efcd/25)

Comment: You can probably get rid of the duplicates if you do group_concat(distinct genre_name).

Comment: nice, thanks for the help :) i was crushing my brain